# Default Value for "this" parameter in C# Extension methods

Tags: c#, oop, c#-4.0, extension-methods, default-value

Why can't I give default parameter value to extension method's `this` parameter?

```
public static User CheckLogin(this User user = null)
{
    ...
}
```

> Error 108 Cannot specify a default value for the 'this' parameter

But, when I write like the following, the compilation succeeds.

```
public static User CheckLogin([DefaultValue(null)]this User user)
{
    ...
}
```

Can anyone explain the reason why MS restricts the first kind of default parameter assignment while allowing the second?

Comment: I'd say an extention method needs to be assocciated with an instance of an object, and therefore a default `this` does not seem to make any sense. Why would you want a default `this`?

Comment: @Bazzz I just wondered why VS didn't show any compilation error. I know it can't be called with a null.

Comment: @SenJacob Actually you can call an extension method will a null item because the compiler changes it to a static method call. `User u = null; u.CheckLogin();`. I tend to null check `this` in my extension methods to avoid clangers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are not comparable concepts. The first is compiler supported optional parameters, the second is meta-data default values for things like design tools (it has no direct compiler support for method calling in code). It is nonsensical to have a default value for the `this` parameter of an extension method because the value will be derived from the call target.

My best guess as to why they don't support optional parameters for `this` in an extension method is limited returns (cost of implementation vs benefit to developer) and a confusion of coding style. Extension methods style themselves as fake extra methods on existing types, so `this` is pretty well fixed to the type you are extending. Wanting to change `this` is tantamount to wanting to change the style that extension methods are offering, so you may as well not use them.

If you want it to be optional, don't use extension methods, use static methods instead:

```
public static User CheckLogin(User user = null)
{
   // etc
}
```

Then call the "old" way:

```
var user = UserUtils.CheckLogin(/* optional user here */);
```